# In Vue.js, use a ternary operator to determine the image source

Tags: vue.js, ternary

I have this line of code in a Vue.js application, which renders the image from a "property" in a list of "properties":

```
<?php $fallback = get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/project-1.jpg' ?>
<img :src="property.img != null ? property.img.medium : '<?php echo $fallback ?>'" :alt="property.name" class="card__image">
```

As you can see, it has a fallback written in PHP, this works. But I want to simply do this:

```
<img :src="property.img != null ? property.img.medium : property.img.original" :alt="property.name" class="card__image">
```

In this case, this doesn't work even though "property.image.original does exist within the property Object, why is that?

Comment: Do you intentionally have both `property.img` and `property.image` or is that a typo?

Comment: Just a typo, it doesn't work even if it's "property.img.original"

Comment: If `property.img` is null, then `property.img.original` will throw a `referenceError`

Comment: And can you show me how could I do a conditional in this case? I'm new in Vue. I have tried a v-if and v-else but I'm new in Vue and I can't make it work.

Comment: Post the code section where you set the property object.

Comment: The ternary expression (conditional) is fine, the problem is you're trying to show `property.img.original` when `property.img` is null, which can't happen.  If it's null, it can't have an `original` property.

Comment: So shouldn't this work? It still doesn't ```<img :src="property.img ? property.img.medium : property.img.original" :alt="property.name" class="card__image">```

Comment: Same issue: how could `property.img.original` be shown?  The ternary checks if `propery.img` is defined.  If it's not, it tries to show `property.img.original`, which makes no sense in that condition, since `property.img` is not defined.

Comment: Maybe `property.img` is always defined and what you mean to do is show `original` if `medium` is not defined.  If so, try this instead:  `:src="property.img.medium || property.img.original"`

Comment: Also looking at the php code the fallback image is hardcoded. So perhaps :src="(property.img && property.img.medium) || '/assets/img/project-1.jpg'" could work for you.

Comment: Nothing of that works I'm afraid, I'm surprised is it so hard to fall back to a second possible value in Vue. property.img is always defined, it always has a value, yet thing slike ```:src="property.img.medium || property.img.original``` throw errors

Comment: It seems you've misunderstood some things.  Your best bet is to post all of your code.

Comment: At the end this worked: ```:src="property.img != null ? property.img.medium || property.img.original : '<?php echo $fallback ?>'``` , Thanks a lot for the help Dan, upvoting all of your answers.